# Change in standard Gibbs energy is always zero?

Tags: thermodynamics

So I have this statement from our professor :

> We have $\Delta G^\circ = -RT\ln K$ and under standard conditions the activities of all substances in the reaction is $1$ ($a=1$), therefore $\Delta G^\circ > 0$.

I dont understand it.If every $a=1$, then $K = 1$ (as the division of activities) and thus $\ln K =0$ which would make $\Delta G^\circ = 0$ as well instead of $>0$,right?

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour). Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this ‎one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/111/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown. If that is really the statement given, then it is wrong indeed. The main thing is that $^\circ$ points to standard state which does not include a rule that activities must all be one. See [this](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/41864/27806).

Answer (score 6):

No. $K$ is not a ratio of instantaneous activities! Let's say you hypothetically prepare a system where all components have unit activity. In that case you would have the **reaction quotient**

$$Q = \prod_i a_i^{\nu_i} = 1$$

but $K$ is the ratio of activities **at equilibrium**. If that hypothetical system is not at equilibrium, then it will go towards equilibrium. When it reaches equilibrium, the activities are no longer going to be equal to unity, and $K$ will not be equal to 1.

Answer (score 6):

The complete equation is $$\Delta G=\Delta G^\circ+RT\ln{Q}$$If $Q=1$, then $$\Delta G=\Delta G^\circ$$Maybe your professor meant to conclude that $\Delta G \neq 0$ if all the activities are equal to 1.  It's hard to know what he meant to say.