# What does "heat is evolved at standard-state conditions" mean?

Tags: enthalpy, heat

> When $\pu{0.539 g}$ of $\ce{Na(s)}$ reacts with excess $\ce{F2(g)}$ to form $\ce{NaF(s)}$, $\pu{13.3 kJ}$ of heat is evolved at standard-state conditions. What is the standard enthalpy of formation ($\Delta_\mathrm{f}H^\circ$) of $\ce{NaF(s)}$?

I am *not* asking for the answer. What I would like to know is what "$\pu{13.3 kJ}$ of heat is evolved at standard-state conditions" means. Does anyone know? I am unfamiliar with this terminology.

Comment: That is incorrect. Standard state **does not include any stipulation of temperature**. See https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/41862/16683

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that the experiment was carried out under a standard pressure.

This standard pressure can be defined by you to be anything. You may define it to be 1 atm, or 5 atm, or 3 Pa. However, the established convention is to define the standard pressure as $p^\circ = \pu{1 bar}$. See: [standard state in the IUPAC Gold Book](https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/S/S05925.html)

What implications does it have for your question? Nothing, really. It just means that the value of $\Delta H$ you derive can be labelled with the word "standard". If you run your reaction at a different pressure $p \neq p^\circ$, then the enthalpy of formation has to be labelled $\Delta_\mathrm{f}H$ instead of $\Delta_\mathrm{f}H^\circ$.

**Note that there is no stipulation of temperature.** Therefore, the reaction may have been carried out at 10 K, or 1000 K, and it **does not have to be 298 K**. This simply means that every different temperature will have a different value of $\Delta_\mathrm{f}H^\circ$.