# Log(Q) is zero, therefore the effect of temperature change is unaccounted for by Nernst Equation?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, reduction-potential

I have an internal assessment on Nernst Equation. The experiment is seeing how changing temperature effects cell potential. The solution are zinc and copper sulfate with each having concentration of 1M.

I have read online on many sources that Q in the Nernst equation is calculated based on the initial concentration values. In my case that is 1M for both the product and the reactant, hence Q=1 and log(Q)=0. If log(Q)=0, then the whole left part of the Nernst equation(E=E°-RT*log(Q)/nF) is equal to zero (E=E°-0) and therefore E=E°. However, I have changed the temperature and my experimental results do show a change in cell potential with changing temperature, but how can I calculate that change in cell potential with changing temperature theoretically.

Thank you.

Comment: The standard potential applies when the temperature is the standard temperature. So changing the temperature changes the standard potential. Now you need to research that and best of success!

Comment: The full answer was given by @orthocresol [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/80937/79678). Sorry I did not find this last month!